# EE v2.7.3 -- blog post won't upload with picture attached

Tags: file-uploads, image

This is an ongoing issue with the build we use for one of our sites, v2.7.3.

Posts won't upload (or save changes at all) if there is an image attached. The post will upload as long as I do not attach an image, but then even if I try to attach the image once uploaded the change just won't take.

I don't know if it is related, but posts also won't appear at the top of list unless they are backdated in the 'publication date' box, which can be frustrating but at least there is a workaround.

I don't have the correct access to update the build or mess around with admin settings, so will have to put in a request to modify anything like that.

Many thanks in advance

Charlie

Comment: Are you able to upload the file through file manager? also make sure that upload directory has correct permissions.

Comment: Hi @JainilNagar, thanks for your response. The file will upload into the editor. I can upload the image into the post and it will show up, but when I submit I just get taken back to the create page, with no green tick of acknowledgement. Where should I go to check permissions?

Comment: So it's not the problem regarding file upload. Please check this [link](https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/237493) which have similar kind of issue.